# I cannot use termios.h in cygwin64

Tags: windows, cygwin, termios

I am making an application where I think I will need to use `termios.h` But I have windows 10. I installed cygwin64. I type in `gcc test.c -o test.exe` in the terminal. I still get `fatal error: termios.h: No such file or directory #include <termios.h>` Is there something I had to do during installation?

The code is just prints hello world but I included `termios.h`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(){
     printf("Hello World!");

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the missing development package. To find which is, use `cygcheck`

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/termios.h
Found 12 matches for usr/include/termios.h
cygwin-devel-3.0.7-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
...
cygwin-devel-3.2.0-0.1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-3.2.0-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
...
```

You need `cygwin-devel`

```
$ cygcheck -l cygwin-devel |grep termios.h
/usr/include/termios.h
/usr/include/machine/termios.h
/usr/include/sys/termios.h
```

looking at your example

```
$ cat prova.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(){
     printf("Hello World!");

     return 0;
}
```

and at the compiler

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
```

the example builds fine

```
$ gcc -Wall prova.c -o prova
$ ./prova
Hello World!
```

Comment: Did the second command, then I tried ``/usr/include/termios.h`` No such file or directory

Comment: to install any package use setup. Cygcheck is for checking AFTER the package is installed

Comment: Alright, sorry. I installed the package and ran ``cygcheck -l cygwin-devel |grep termios.h`` It found it in the directories that you showed but when I run ``gcc test.c -o text.exe`` I get the same error

Comment: please show the code and how you are compiling it

Comment: Added the code, just hello world but I included ``termios.h`` I open cygwin64 and type in ``gcc test.c -o text.exe`` after going to the directory where the test file is

Comment: Didnt see the edit, sorry. Thanks dude, I figured out I was using an outdated version of gcc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

`#include <termios.h>`

This:

`#include <sys/termios.h>`

Comment: Wrong answer https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html

Comment: Right answer https://github.com/cygwin/cygwin/blob/main/winsup/cygwin/include/sys/termios.h